# How to every read three lines into html table from var?

Tags: shell

I set Var:

ImgPath=$(find $PWD -depth -maxdepth 3 -name "*Cpu_U*.gif" -o -name "*Cpu_S*.gif" -o -name "*Memory_Free.gif" | sort -n)

every read three lines from var into html table.

i write script:

```
#!/bin/sh

  ImgPath=$(find $PWD -depth -maxdepth 3 -name "*Cpu_U*.gif" -o -name "*Cpu_S*.gif" -o -name "*Memory_Free.gif" | sort -n)

  cat <<EOF1>report.html
  <html>
  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td width="15%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">TestCase</span></td>
  <td width="15%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">Grinder Component</span></td>
  <td width="15%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">Grinder Component</span></td>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">value</span></td>
  <td width="15%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">JVM Arguments </span></td>
  <td width="25%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">value</span></td>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">OS Kernal </span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#00FFFF"><span class="STYLE5">Value</span></td></tr>

  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"></span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">runMode</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">continuous</span></td>
  <td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE10">Jvm.argument</span></td>
  <td rowspan="2"><span class="STYLE10">Hotspot:</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">runMode</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1</span></td></tr>

  <tr><td><span class="STYLE10">durationHour</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1</span></td>"
  <td><span class="STYLE10">durationHour</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1</span></td></tr>

  <tr><td><span class="STYLE10">processors</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1</span></td>
  <td rowspan="3"><span class="STYLE10">JRockit:</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">processors</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">10</span></td></tr>

  <tr><td><span class="STYLE10">threads</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">10</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">threads</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1000</span></td></tr>

  <tr><td><span class="STYLE10">arrayLength</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">1000</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE10">arrayLength</span></td>
  <td><span class="STYLE9"></span></td></tr></table>

EOF1

while read line; do
      case $((i++ % 3)) in
          3) echo -n "$s";;
      esac
done<report.html

  cat <<EOF2 >> report.html

  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>
  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>
   <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>
  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>
  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>
  <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#333333">
  <tr><td rowspan="5"><span class="STYLE9"><a href=\"$img\"><img src="$ImgPath" /a></span></td></tr></table>

  </html>
EOF2
```

but insert to all  lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
  case $((i++ % 3)) in
      3) echo -n "$s";;
  esac
```

does not what you want. `i++ % 3` is 0, 1, or 2, but never 3.

Comment: Thanks ! how to modify it ?

Comment: @GangYan Replace `3)` with `(2)`. And you should initialize `i=0` first. Also, `$s` is never assigned. Did you mean `$line` instead?

Comment: while read line; do
      case $((i=0 i++ % 2)) in
          3) echo -n "$s";;
      esac
done<report.html

Comment: Thanks reply! i modify: while read line; do
      case $((i=0 i++ % 2)) in
          3) echo -n "$line";;
      esac
done<report.html  but run error: image.sh: line 48: i=0 i++ % 2: syntax error in expression (error token is "i++ % 2")